# Select class inside a parent class using this

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

When someone clicks on `addMass` class then i want to add `data-rate` to the `currentMass` class. There can be many `addToCart` classes So i need to make changes to the one that is clicked at that moment.

See the following Code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="addToCart">
    <button class="minusMass twitchButton">-</button>
    <button class="addToCartButton" data-rate="1">Add <span class="currentMass"></span> Kg</button>
    <button class="addMass twitchButton">+</button>
    <div class="clear"></div>   
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var mass = 0;   

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".currentMass").html(mass);
    $(".addToCart").on("click", ".addMass", function() {
        var cm = Number($(this).prev("button.addToCartButton").find(".currentMass").text());
        var increment_rate = Number($(this).find(".currentMass").attr("data-rate"));
        cm = cm + increment_rate;
        $(".currentMass").html(cm);
    });
});
```

Comment: in first call you use prev and you don't on the second, and as a side note you should save `.currentMass` element in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already doing it while reading `cm`, find the descendant element of the previous sibling of the clicked element

```js
var mass = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".currentMass").html(mass);

  $(".addToCart").on("click", ".addMass", function() {
    var $mass = $(this).prev("button.addToCartButton").find(".currentMass");
    var increment_rate = $(this).prev(".addToCartButton").data("rate");
    $mass.html(+$mass.text() + increment_rate);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addToCart">
  <button class="minusMass twitchButton">-</button>
  <button class="addToCartButton" data-rate="1">Add <span class="currentMass"></span> Kg</button>
  <button class="addMass twitchButton">+</button>

  <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the target element with `.prev()` as the target element `.currentMass` is the child of clicked button's sibling:

```
$(this).prev('button').find(".currentMass").html(cm);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a different approach.

Instead of operating business login directly on the GUI elements, try to create a cart status using a JSON structure and let the GUI display the cart status based on the JSON structure.

It is basically an MVC approach. Not sure if you are already using any MVC framework. But in vanilla JavaScript you should leverage on the following elements:

- a variable that represent the cart
- a cart manager object that implements the business logic through a set of methods (e.g. addMass, removeMass, addItem, removeItem).
- a set of handlers that listens to the GUI events, invokes the corresponding cart manager methods and eventually refresh the GUI contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `siblings`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".currentMass").html(0);
  $(".addMass").click(function() {

    var cm = $(this).siblings(".addToCartButton").find(".currentMass").html();
    var incr = $(this).siblings(".addToCartButton").attr("data-rate");

    $(this).siblings(".addToCartButton").find(".currentMass").html(parseInt(cm) + parseInt(incr))
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
First : <div class="addToCart">
  <button class="minusMass twitchButton">-</button>
  <button class="addToCartButton" data-rate="1">Add <span class="currentMass"></span> Kg</button>
  <button class="addMass twitchButton">+</button>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<br>
Second : <div class="addToCart">
  <button class="minusMass twitchButton">-</button>
  <button class="addToCartButton" data-rate="5">Add <span class="currentMass"></span> Kg</button>
  <button class="addMass twitchButton">+</button>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```